# Akka.Net stream is slower than parallel loop

Tags: c#, .net, akka.net

I have the following two codes:

```
var jbesSource = Source.From(jobSeekers);
var runnableGraph = jbesSource
    .Via(Flow.FromGraph(GraphDsl.Create(b =>
    {
        Flow<(JobSeeker_JBE, List<JBE>), Dictionary<JBE, ICollection<JobCI>>, NotUsed> worker =
        FindJobsFlow.Instance(cache);
        var merge = b.Add(new Merge<Dictionary<JBE, ICollection<JobCI>>>(8));
        var balancer2 = b.Add(new Balance<JobSeeker_JBE>(8));

        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);
        b.From(balancer2).Via(filterJobAlertsFlow).Via(worker).To(merge);

        return new FlowShape<JobSeeker_JBE, Dictionary<JBE, ICollection<JobCI>>>
                   (balancer2.In, merge.Out);
    })).Async())
        .Async()
        .ToMaterialized(Sink.Seq<Dictionary<JBE, ICollection<JobCI>>>(), Keep.Right);
```

This is much faster than the above:

```
Parallel.ForEach(jobseekers, js =>
{
    var jobs = FindJobs(js);
}
```

Both are doing exactly the same work.

The FindJobs function consume a REST API, so it's IO basically.

Any ideas why a simple loop would be much faster than Akka.Streaming?

Comment: To be fair to akka.net, they are **not** doing the exact same work.  Your second is only getting the jobs our of one `js` and is not merging the lists in any way.  I don't know enough about akka.net to say why one is faster than the other.

Comment: It's quicker to pick up a hammer and start driving nails (`Parallel.ForEach()`) but it's more efficient in the long-run to build a house with a nailgun (Akka.NET streams). They are different tools.

Answer (score 2):

**Akka.NET streams primary use case is to work over long (potentially infinite) streams of events that can consist of many different processing steps.** If calling several jobs in parallel is what you want, this is definitely not an appropriate tool for your need.

That being said if you want to process different events asynchronously you can to it like that:

```
jbesSource
    // use SelectAsync if the order of output values must match order of inputs
    .SelectAsyncUnordered(maxParallelism, FindJobsAsync)
    .RunWith(Sink.Seq<T>(), materializer);
```

Where `maxParallelism` could be for example `Environment.ProcessorCount` or any value matching the number of your machine cores.